# Group results returned from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying a database that was built by an ex employee, badly! I have successfully gathered and outputted all the data I need - however I want to group the data into Issue numbers.

At the moment the output is like this…

```
Company 1
Issue number: 142
Total: 480.00

Company 2
Issue number: 142
Total: 46

Company 3
Issue number: 142
Total: 240.00

Company 4
Issue number: 142
Total: 420.00

Company 5
Issue number: 142
Total: 468.00

Company 6
Issue number: 142
Total: 252.00
```

I'd like it to read like…

```
**Issue number: 142**
Company 1 Total 480
Company 2 Total 468
etc etc I.e grouping them into issue numbers.
```

Here's my code…

```
$sql = "
SELECT bf_total_cost
     , bf_date_added
     , ib_issue_number
     , companyname
     , contacts_id
     , bf_id
     , bf_company_id
     , ib_booking_form_number 
  FROM contacts
     , booking_form
     , issues_booked 
 WHERE ib_issue_number >= 141 
   AND ib_issue_number <= 165 
   AND bf_date_added >= '2014-11-01' 
   AND bf_date_added <= '2016-08-31' 
   AND contacts_id = bf_company_id 
   AND bf_id = ib_booking_form_number 
 ORDER 
    BY ib_issue_number ASC;
";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>'.$row['companyname'] .'</li>';
echo '<li>'.$row['ib_issue_number'] .'</li>';
echo '<li>'.$row['bf_total_cost'] .'</li>';
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I'd like to show how much each company spent in each issue.

Comment: `while($row=mysql_...) {$groupedArray[$row['issue number']][] = $row;}`.

Comment: You want the issue number to be shown once. Right?

Comment: Yes that's right - with the bookings for that issue listed underneath

Comment: Note that your join style dates from 1992, and your API was deprecated a year or so ago.

Comment: Not sure what that means @Strawberry but thanks for the advice

Comment: It means you might want to familiarise yourself with a recent book or tutorial on PHP and MySQL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a nested/grouped array in the `while` loop while you fetch the rows from result:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$groupedArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $groupedArray[$row['ib_issue_number']][] = $row;
}
```

You can then output it as a nested HTML list    :

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($groupedArray as $issueNumber => $group) {
    echo "<li>issue number: $issueNumber <ul>";
    foreach ($group as $row) {
        echo "<li>Company: {$row['companyname']}; Total {$row['bf_total_cost']}</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to show £0.00 if an Issue wasn't booked? I.e if the issue wasn't booked it still has a value as to create a full issue list as opposed to only those that have a booking?

Comment: What do you mean by "Issue wasn't booked" in terms of data? Wich columnd would have wich value? Hpwever, sounds like a basic programming task wis an if-condition.

Comment: I now have the company name down the left hand the issues along the top and then the amount the company spent underneath. Where I'm struggling is the query returns the results in order,If someone booked issue 142, then 147 it would show them as having booked 142 and 143 etc etc … I need to find a way to place a value of £0.00 into the issues that were not booked.

Comment: Sorry, i can't follow you. It seems to be too much for a comment. So you should write a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation in MySQL:

```
 SELECT sum(bf_total_cost) ... GROUP BY ib_issue_number, bf_company_id
```

This will group every row by the issue number and company id.  Then sum() will return the total cost of each grouping.

If you want just to group by the issue number, remove bf_company_id from the group by.

Comment: Hi @Devon it sounds like you know what I'm trying to do but it's still not working, are you able to put what your saying into fiddle?

Comment: You need to provide more info on what isn't working.  If you're not familiar enough with PHP or MySQL, then I really can't help you with that.

Comment: How do I output what you have mentioned … so I've got:

`$sql = "SELECT sum(bf_total_cost), bf_date_added, ib_issue_number, companyname, contacts_id, bf_id, bf_company_id, ib_booking_form_number 
 FROM contacts, booking_form, issues_booked 
 GROUP BY ib_issue_number
 WHERE  ib_issue_number >= '141' AND ib_issue_number <= '165' AND bf_date_added >= '2014-11-01' AND  bf_date_added <= '2016-08-31' AND contacts_id = bf_company_id AND bf_id = ib_booking_form_number 
 
 ORDER BY ib_issue_number ASC ";`

How do I now output this?

Comment: Your group by is not in the correct location.  Read the MySQL manual on syntax.